# Why is my program shifting s and c by the wrong amount if I enter 5 into my program but not with any other letters or number?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, eval

This program is meant to ask you for a sentence and a number then it shifts the letters down the alphabet all by the inputted number and then lets you undo it by shift it by minus what you enter. For some reason when you enter `5` as your shift the letter s shift to different random letters and does not give you the correct word when you try and shift back and I have no idea why.

```
import sys
import time
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
            "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m,
 n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
                                            15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26) 
def program():

    def encryption():

        def encryption1():
            global message
            global shift
            message = list ((input ("Please enter the sentence you would like to be %s\n>" % (EnDe1))).lower())
            print ("To %s your message please %s your private key number (from 1 - 10)" % (EnDe2, EnDe3))
            shift = int (input (">"))
            if EnDe == "b":
                shift = - (shift)
            if shift < 11 or shift > 0:
                for x in range(len(message)):        
                    if message[x] != " ":
                        if eval(message[x]) > 26 - shift:
                            message[x] = letters[eval(message[x]) + shift - 27]
                        else:
                            message[x] = letters[eval(message[x]) + shift - 1]
            else:
                shift = int (input ("only numbers from 1 to 10 are accepted, try again\n>"))
                encryption1()

        def choice():
            global EnDe
            global EnDe1
            global EnDe2
            global EnDe3
            EnDe = (input ("would you like to A)encrypt or B)decrypt\n>")).lower()
            if EnDe == "a":
                EnDe1 = "encrypted"
                EnDe2 = "encrypt"
                EnDe3 = "pick"
                encryption1()
            elif EnDe == "b":
                EnDe1 = "decrypted"
                EnDe2 = "decrypt"
                EnDe3 = "enter"
                encryption1()
            else:
                print ("please pick either 'A' or 'B' , ONLY!")
                time.sleep(2)
                choice()

        choice()              
        output = ''.join(message)
        print (output)
        retry = input ("would you like to Decrypt/Encrypt another message? (Y/N)\n>")
        retry = retry.lower()

        while retry != ("y" or "n"):
            retry = input ("please select either y or n\n>")
            retry = retry.lower()

        while retry == "y":
            program()
        else:
            sys.exit()
    encryption()
```

Comment: Why don’t you install [`pudb`](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/) and debug your code?

Comment: Unrelated: `shift < 11 or shift > 0` should be `shift < 11 and shift > 0` or more pythonic: `0 < shift < 11`

Comment: Please don't call this encryption... encoding, maybe but this is no better than ROT13

Comment: Unrelated: `retry != ("y" or "n")` does not work like that. You should do `retry not in "yn"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define a global `x` variable, and also a local one. The local one shadows the global one and so the result of `eval("x")` is not anymore what you expected to have.

Solution: use a different variable for the `for` loop.

There is much that can be improved in your code. You can take advantage of the modulo operator and the `ord` function, avoiding the need for all those 26 letter names.

Here is how that `for` loop could look without all that:

```
if 0 < shift < 11:
    for i, ch in enumerate(message): 
        if ch != " ":
            message[i] = chr((ord(ch)-ord('a')+shift)%26+ord('a'))
```

Unrelated: note that `retry != ("y" or "n")` does not work like that. You should do `retry not in "yn"`